# what's wrong? dangling pointer?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Returning the address of local or temporary variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744264/returning-the-address-of-local-or-temporary-variable)
>   [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int *p = NULL;

void 
fun(void){
    int i = 10;
    p = &i;
}

int 
main(void){
    fun();
    cout<<*p<<endl; //#1
    cout<<*p<<endl; //#2
    return 0;
}
```

I think #1 and #2 will output the same, but why #1 output 10 and #2 output a random number?

Comment: You're making a pointer point to a stack variable which is destroyed and then dereferencing the pointer, producing undefined behaviour

Comment: Undefined behavior which means you can get the expected output (http://ideone.com/VMYzG) or some other result (http://codepad.org/OiN8n1L0)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is just undefined behavior. You're working with a pointer to a local variable, after that variable has gone out of scope. Anything could happen.

Comment: so #1 should output a random number?

Comment: @tinybit: You need to realize that it's quite pointless to reason about what "should" happen. It's **undefined behavior**.

Comment: @tinybit: It shouldn't do anything specific.  "Anything could happen".

Comment: I get it. #1 out 10 confused me, what I thout was right. Thank you!

Comment: @tinybit 10 is a random number :)

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed a dangling pointer.

You are assigning `p` to point to an automatic (local) object. Once `fun` has returned, the object no longer exists, and attempting to access it through `p` gives undefined behaviour.

If you're interested in why you observe that particular behaviour: on most platforms, the stack frame of `fun` will still exist until another function is called. So reading `p` for the first call to `<<` is quite likely to find the old value of `i`. After calling `<<`, the old stack frame has most likely been overwritten, so reading `p` will find an arbitrary value. But none of this is behaviour you can rely on; accessing the dead object could cause a crash, or any other behaviour.

Comment: +1 for explaining possible causes for output. While UB can't be relied on, one needs to be able to recognize the effects.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `p` becomes a dangling pointer the moment `fun()` returns.

Answer (score 1):

You are saving a pointer to a variable that is out of scope. Thus, the [behavior is undefined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). It can print anything, or even crash your application. Or even make your computer explode.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is returning a pointer to something that gets over-written:

```
int i = 10;
p = &i; // This line
```

Because `i` is a local variable.