# C++ Basic concept regarding reference operator return type

Tags: c++, function, reference, operator-keyword

I need to clear a basic concept. This code works fine. Can somebody explain me that if the function calDouble already returning the address (reference) of int why I need to use & operator further in main int *j = &calDouble(i); to get the address (reference) of int? Thanks.

```
int& calDouble(int x)
{
    x = x*2;
    return x;

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 99;
    int *j = &calDouble(i);

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You should probably change `int& calDouble(int x)` to `int& calDouble(int& x)` so that you're not returning a dangling reference to `x`.

Comment: Actually, your code *doesn't* work.  You can't treat the same parameter as a value, and then return it as a reference.  I think your question is fine.  But I also think it illustrates just what a *horrible* language C++ is - the perverse mistakes it lets you make - without even giving you an inkling there's a problem.  Multiply one short, apparently simple example like this by all the millions (billions?) of lines of (potentially buggy) C++ code inflicted on an unsuspecting world...

Comment: "works fine" I mean it compiled without error.

Comment: @developer: Then, you have a faulty compiler, because mine warned about returning a reference to a local variable.

Comment: @user315052: I know. but right now that's a seperate issue for me... btw which compiler are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning the address of local or temporary variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744264/returning-the-address-of-local-or-temporary-variable)

Comment: The edit you made completely changed the question. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int& calDouble(int x)` doesn't return an address, but a reference to an `int`.

You need to take the address of the reference to be able to assign it to a pointer.

Note however that your code invokes **undefined behavior**. Because you pass the parameter by value, a copy of it is created inside the function. So you return a local variable by reference, which is not legal.

I think your confusion comes from `&`. This can be used in two ways:

- applied to a variable `&x`, it takes its address
- when in a declaration `int& x`, it defines a reference

A reference is just an alias, a different name for a variable.

```
int x = 0;
int& y = x;
```

Now, `x` and `y` refer to the same variable.

```
int* z = &x;
```

takes the address of `x`.

Comment: What is the difference between the address and reference. I guess this is where I'm confused.

Comment: @developer - Here's a good tutorial on C++ "references": http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html.  C has an "addressof" operator ("&"), but only C++ has "references".

Comment: @Luchain Grigore: Excellent explanation in your edited answer. You are right that I'm confused with the & operator which is behaving in 2 different ways. So here the function "int& calDouble(int &x)" is returning a reference of x like any other reference variable and not the value. And reference variable is just an alias of a variable. What exactly does it contain in it : a memory address of the variable it refers to?

Comment: @developer It's implementation defined. But you should think of it as an alias. A nickname. Everywhere you write `y`, you should think `x`. :)

Answer (score 1):

`int&` is a reference type. It is **not** the address.

To see what `&calDouble(i)` does, consider if we had broken it into two statements:

```
int& x = calDouble(i);
... = &x;
```

The `calDouble()` function returns a reference type, and the prepended `&` then takes the *address-of* whatever was returned. So the type is now `int*`, which is why that line compiles.

However, your program exhibits undefined behavior! The `x` in `calDouble()` goes away once the function ends. The value that was originally there *may still be in memory*, which is why your program "works". But this is not reliable in production code, and one day your perfectly working test program may blow-up the moment it's deployed.

It's generally a bad idea to return a reference to a local variable for this vary reason. (You'll see class methods return references to member data, which is fine as long as the object is still in scope since those variables will still exist.) Just return a regular `int` and get on with life. An optimizing compiler can do some [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) if you're really worried about performance when returning large objects.

Comment: I know it is bad idea returning a refence of a local variable... I  was not concerned abou it right now... my main focus is regarding reference type and address. What's the difference between these two.

Comment: @developer - See my [link](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html) above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explaination. It did help me too.