# returning references to local variable

Tags: c++, reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Returning the address of local or temporary variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744264/returning-the-address-of-local-or-temporary-variable)
>   [Can a local variable’s memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Even knowing what happens as a result of the following snips it would be helpful to understand how it is happening. Four questions follow.

Given:

```
int& foo()
{
    int i = 1;
    return i;
}
```

And knowing that in the following a reference to the **local named i** is de-referenced into a temp that is assigned to intVal and **local i** disappears at the end of *foo()*

```
int  intVal = foo();
```

First question - in the following, the right hand side of the expression is the same as above so is this a case where the compiler sees the left hand side and, based on context, knows not to de-reference the returned reference, and instead to create a new reference is initialized with it?

Second question - and this alone makes the **local i** stick around while intRef is in scope?

```
int& intRef = foo();
```

Third question - bellow *intPtr* gets address of **local i**. So, is the compiler using the context of the assignment and deciding to not de-reference to get a value before taking the address of the reference (rather than say taking the address of a temp containing the de-referenced value)?

Fourth question - does **local i** stick around while *intPtr* is in scope?

```
int* intPtr = &foo();
```

Comment: It's pointless to know what happens here. FWIW, it *never* sticks around, and in the first one it does not stick around long enough for anything to happen.

Comment: possible duplicate: [Returning the address of local or temporary variable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2744264/187543)

Comment: Closed due to exact duplicate?  My main concern was questions 1 and 3 which concern the context on the LHS determining how the RHS was handled (dereferenced or not).  Neither "exact duplicate" even touches on this issue.

Answer (score 6):

Nope, none of those will extend the lifetime of the local variable. *Nothing* in C++ will have that effect. Local objects in C++ live until the end of the scope in which they are declared, end of story.

The only rule which, at first glance, seems to follow different rules is this:

```
int foo() {
    return 42;
}

int main() {
    const int& i = foo();
    // here, `i` is a reference to the temporary that was returned from `foo`, and whose lifetime has been extended
}
```

That is, a *const* reference can extend the lifetime of a *temporary* being assigned to it.

But that requires the function to return a value, not a reference, and the callee to bind the return value to a const reference, neither of which are done in your code.

Comment: "requires the function to return a value, not a reference" <- you should write this in caps, with a bold font! :)

Answer (score 0):

In no case (not intVal, not intRef, and not intPtr) does `i` necessarily stick around after foo returns.

The value on the stack which was previously occupied by i may or may not be changed at any time, after foo returns.

For example (on some CPUs and O/Ses), it is likely to be changed by any subsequent call to a subroutine, and may be changed if a hardware interrupt occurs.