# c++ function returning incorrect array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

I am trying to create a function called `getSortedRanks` which returns an array. I copied the format for returning arrays from this question [Return array in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473438/return-array-in-a-function) but the array is not being returned correctly.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define familyMembers 4

int *getSortedRanks()
{
    int rankedMembers[familyMembers] = {3,4,2,1};
    return rankedMembers;
}

int main()
{
    int *sortedRanks = getSortedRanks();

    //print the returned array
    for(int i = 0; i < familyMembers; i ++)
    {
        cout << "ranked member is " << sortedRanks[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this the output is:

```
ranked member is 3
ranked member is 0
ranked member is 0
ranked member is 2686744
```

The first element of the array `sortedRanks` is always correct but the others are not. How can I correct the way the array is being returned?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4643713/1741542, http://stackoverflow.com/q/7499864/1741542, http://stackoverflow.com/q/13980362/1741542, http://stackoverflow.com/q/423186/1741542 should give you a hint.

Comment: Don't return pointers to things that live on the function's stack.

Comment: Why are you using a macro instead of a static int?

Comment: @Brian rather `const`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An array with automatic storage duration:

```
int rankedMembers[familyMembers] = {3, 4, 2, 1};
```

lives on the stack and gets destroyed after `getSortedRanks` finishes. The returned pointer is invalidated. Dereferencing it leads to [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367633/what-are-all-the-common-undefined-behaviours-that-a-c-programmer-should-know-a).

You'll either want to:

1. Allocate the array dynamically (on the heap), as you'll manage its lifetime:

   ```
   int *getSortedRanks()
   {
       return new int[familyMembers]{3, 4, 2, 1};
   }
   ```

   Don't forget to `delete []` it after the use. Using [smart pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713484/smart-pointers-and-arrays) will help you with that.
2. Use `std::vector` or `std::array` and return by value:

   ```
   std::array<int, familyMembers> getSortedRanks()
   {
       return {3, 4, 2, 1};
   }
   ```

(ordered from less to more favorable)

Comment: I get it now. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: The array `rankedMembers` is not statically allocated.   The reason it does not exist after the function returns is that it has automatic storage duration.