# Why am I getting Segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, undefined-behavior

I am trying to learn how to use structures and linked lists in *C* but I really don't understand why the following code gives me Segmentation fault:

I have 3 files named *list.h, operations.c and main.c*. In the file *list.h*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef char DATA;

struct linked_list {
    DATA                   d;
    struct linked_list *next;
};

typedef struct linked_list ELEMENT;
typedef ELEMENT              *LINK;

LINK string_to_list(char s[]);
void print_list(LINK);
```

The file *operations.c*:

```
#include "list.h"

LINK string_to_list(char s[]){
    LINK head = NULL;

    if (s[0]) {
        ELEMENT c = {s[0], NULL};
        c.next = string_to_list(s+1);
        head = &c;
    }

    return head;
}

void print_list(LINK head) {
    if(head != NULL){
        putchar(head -> d);
        print_list(head -> next);
    } else {
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

The file *main.c*:

```
#include "list.h"

int main(void) {
    LINK head = string_to_list("wtf");
    print_list(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Never return references to local storage.

Comment: As this stands, you will not be able to have more than 1 element to your list without some dynamic memory allocation or some fancy pool work.

Comment: @CaptainSkyhawk: Actually he does, but not for long.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744264/returning-the-address-of-local-or-temporary-variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (s[0]) {
    ELEMENT c = {s[0], NULL};        // Allocate space for struct on the stack
    c.next = string_to_list(s+1);
    head = &c;                       // Save the address to head
}  // <-- poof, c goes out of scope and is deallocated from the stack

return head; // <-- return address of deallocated object
```

Answer (score 2):

In `string_to_list` you are taking the address of a local variable(*which on most modern implementations is stored on the stack*) in your *if statement*:

```
head = &c;
```

and then returning that address here:

```
return head;
```

the variable `c` will no longer exist after the end of the *if statement*, this is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.2.4` *Storage durations of objects* paragraph *2* says:

> [...]If an object is referred to outside of its lifetime, the behavior is undefined.[...]

Answer (score 2):

```
if (s[0]) {
--->    ELEMENT c = {s[0], NULL};
    c.next = string_to_list(s+1);
    head = &c;
}

return head;
```

Is a local memory.  As soon as you leave the function (or even the code block), that memory is freed and is no longer valid.  You need to `malloc()` it, or pass in some memory for this function to use for it to live beyond this function.