# why after calling pointer gives wrong value

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> 

int * add(int *, int *);
int add(int, int);

void main() {
    int a, b, sum, *z;
    cout << "enter the value of a & b";
    cin >> a >> b;
    z = add(&a, &b);
    sum = add(a, b);
    cout << "\nthe sum is: " << sum << endl;
    cout << "the sum is :" << *z << endl;   getch();
}

//.....calling with value..... 
int add(int a, int b) {
    int s;
    s = a + b;
    return s;
}

//......calling with address....... 
int *add(int *a, int*b) {
    int r;
    r = *a + *b;
    return &r;
}
```

Why does it give the wrong answer:

> output........ a=70 b=80 the sum with  value is: 150 the sum with address is :1208

...but when I give the program as:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> 

int * add(int *, int *);
int add(int, int);

void main() {
    int a, b, sum, *z;
    cout << "enter the value of a & b";
    cin >> a >> b;
    sum = add(a, b);
    cout << "\nthe sum is: " << sum << endl;
    z = add(&a, &b);
    cout << "the sum is :" << *z << endl;
    getch();
}

//.....calling with value..... 
int add(int a, int b) {
    int s;
    s = a + b;
    return s;
}

//......calling with address.......     
int *add(int *a, int*b) {
    int r;
    r = *a + *b;
    return &r;
}
```

It gives right answer.

> output..... a=70 b=80 the sum with value is:150 the sum with address is:150.

Why?

Comment: Please also give a hint at the difference between the two programs, that will help us understand you question much better.

Comment: if we declare r as global variable then it will work in both cases .Yeah please give the difference between 2 programs

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ code needs explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409639/c-code-needs-explanation)

Answer (score 5):

```
int *add(int *a,int *b) 
{   
   int r;      // r resides on stack
   r=*a+*b;
   return &r;

} // life time of r ends here.
```

You are returning the address of a local variable causing undefined behavior. Compiler should have warned about it.

Answer (score 3):

When you return the address of `r`, in `main`, you have the address of a variable that is on the stack, in an area of stack that is currently "free". Using memory after it has been freed, whether it's "stale stack" or "stale heap" is "undefined behaviour"

In this case, any use of the location of `r` on the stack in the future will overwrite the value in `r` with some other "random" value. In this case, it looks like it may be the address of the function `add` (with `int` parameters).

I would also suggest that you use a more modern compiler (one that isn't old enough to legally apply for a driving license in most countries) and enable warnings. For example GCC  (which is free software, so no cost) - it will give warnings for "returning address of local variable".