# Boolean array returning incorrect values from bitmask?

Tags: c++, arrays, boolean, bit-manipulation

I've written a function that deconstructs a byte into 8 bits and stores those bits as boolean values into a boolean array. However, the boolean array is producing random values which is confusing me since booleans can only hold TRUE and FALSE.

```
// DeconByte :: Deconstructs a byte into a series of bits.
bool* DeconByte( ubyte Value ) {
    bool Bools[ 8 ];

    for( int i = 0; i < 8; i ++ ) {
        Bools[ i ] = ( ( Value >> ( 7 - i ) ) & 1 ) > 0;
    }

    return Bools;
}
```

If you pass a value 255, then the result should be an array of 8 TRUE boolean values as an array. However, the weird part is that not only does my function not return boolean values, but it also returns different values every time without changing the byte intput.

What exactly went wrong?

---

Based on the answers I fixed the problem:

```
// DeconByte :: Deconstructs a byte into a series of bits.
bool* DeconByte( ubyte Value ) {
    bool Bools = new bool[ 8 ];

    for( int i = 0; i < 8; i ++ ) {
        Bools[ i ] = ( ( Value >> i ) & 1 ) > 0;
    }

    return Bools;
}

// Testing:
bool* Bits = DeconByte( 255 );
```

Comment: [The memory allocated to automatic variables will be released when you leave the function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409639/why-does-returning-a-reference-to-a-automatic-variable-work/18409733#18409733), so passing a pointer back to one is undefined behavior.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope. Just return a `std::array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return pointer to a local variable that in general case will be destroyed after exiting the function. So the program has undefined behaviour.

Define the function the following way

```
std::array<bool, 8> DeconByte( ubyte Value ) 
{
    std::array<bool, 8> Bools;

    for( int i = 0; i < 8; i ++ ) {
        Bools[ i ] = ( ( Value >> i ) & 1 ) > 0;
    }

    return Bools;
}
```

Comment: That works too, but I fixed the problem a different way.

Comment: @user3519915 In C++ any task can be done in different ways.:)