# Why can't I return this vector of vectors?

Tags: c++, vector, reference, return

I have a class that declares a vector of vectors of type `char` as the following and contains a method to read half of it and return the resulting vector.

```
class Mapa 
{
private:
    vector<vector<char> > vec;

public:
    //Constructor
    Mapa():vec(0,vector<char>(0)){};

    Mapa(int row, int col):vec(row, vector<char>(col)){};
    virtual ~Mapa(){};
     }

const Mapa& just_Half()
    {

        Mapa temp(vec.size(),vec[0].size());
        int a = vec.size()*vec[0].size()/2;
        for (int i = 0; i < vec.size() && a>0; i++, a--)
            for (int j = 0; j < vec[i].size() && a>0; j++, a--){
                temp.vec[i][j]=vec[i][j];
            }
        return temp;

    }
```

in main I do:

```
Mapa Mapa1(3, 10);
Mapa Mapa2;
Mapa2=Mapa1.just_Half();
```

My question is why is Map2 just and empty vector at the end of this?
Why doesn't it receive temp?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The issue is not related to Visual C++, hence I removed that tag. You're returning a reference to a local variable. The issue has been described in many questions such as http://stackoverflow.com/q/4643713/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/2744264/

Comment: Oops, I wanted to say "The issue is not specific to Visual C++".

Comment: Thanks for the indication. Having a hard time with pointers and references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your return type is a reference to a `Mapa`. The `Mapa` (named `temp` inside the function) you're returning is destructed when the function goes out of scope, so you're returning a destructed `Mapa`, which is undefined.

The solution is simple, return by value instead of by reference:

```
const Mapa just_Half()
{

    Mapa temp(vec.size(),vec[0].size());
    int a = vec.size()*vec[0].size()/2;
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size() && a>0; i++, a--)
        for (int j = 0; j < vec[i].size() && a>0; j++, a--){
            temp.vec[i][j]=vec[i][j];
        }
    return temp;
}
```

If you're concerned that this does an unnecessary copy, don't worry. Compilers will almost always optimize that copy operation away with [return value optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12953129/2297365).

Comment: Yes indeed. But unfortunately I am stuck to using the method as I posted since its an assignment... I kind of sorted it out by using a ' static Mapa temp'

Comment: If I were in your position, I would bring this up with your instructor. Your solution absolutely should not have to be to use a statically allocated `Mapa` object (such that it isn't destructed on function exit).

Comment: Yes. Will do since it also doesn't make much sense to me having to use such a solution... Thanks